# Docker volume mount to kubernetes volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying out to have a volume mount on Kubernetes.

Currently I have a Docker image which I run like:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"<host_dir>,target=<docker_dir> container
```

To have this run on Google Kubernetes cluster, I have:

1. Create a Google Compute Disk
2. Created a persistent volume which refers to the disk:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
...
    namespace: default
    name: pvc
spec:
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pvc
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: disk-name
    fsType: ext4
---
...
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: "storage"
...
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2000Gi
```

3. Created pod with mount

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: pvc
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: pvc
  containers:
    - name: image_name
      image: eu.gcr.io/container:latest
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: <docker_dir>
          name: dir
```

I am missing out where the binding between the host and container/pod directories will take place. Also where do I mention that binding in my yaml files.

I will appreciate any help :)

Comment: You cannot mount your local disk into a remote Kubernetes cluster.  (At all; it's just not possible, unless your local system is running an NFS server or something along those lines.)  What's in the local disk directory; why do you want this volume mount?

Comment: The volume will be used as a persistent storage for the application.

Comment: Please be more specific - do you want to mount you local drive (or directory) a a volume that will be accessible to all your nodes inside the cluster ?

Comment: No. The volume should be available to a single application inside the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path here.  In your Pod spec, the name of the volumeMount should match the name of the volumes.  So in your case,

```
volumes:
    - name: pvc
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: pvc
```

volume name is `pvc`. So your volumeMount should be

```
volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/path/in/container"
          name: pvc
```

So, for example, to mount this volume at `/mydata` in your container, your Pod spec would look like

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: pvc
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: pvc
  containers:
    - name: image_name
      image: eu.gcr.io/container:latest
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mydata"
          name: pvc
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!